# Reactjs - How to prevent assigning of null during editting a form

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create an edit form usinf React with a nodejs backend which links to mysql database. My backend code is peerfect as my data is updating.
The issue I am facing is that whenever I edit a field, the rest of the fields send a null value to the database.
For example:
If I have name: "example", phone: "12345689", email:"example@gmail.com" when I edit name to example1 the data being sent to my database is; name:example1, phone:"", email:""

**This is my form front-end:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function CompanyMaster_Edit(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [CmpnyCode, setCmpnyCode] = useState("");
  const [CmpnyName, setCmpnyName] = useState("");
  const [Address1, setAddress1] = useState("");
  const [Address2, setAddress2] = useState("");
  const [PoBox, setPoBox] = useState("");
  const [City, setCity] = useState("");
  const [Province, setProvince] = useState("");
  const [Country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [Phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [Fax, setFax] = useState("");
  const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [RegistrationNo, setRegistrationNo] = useState("");
  const [VatNo, setVatNo] = useState("");
  const [PinNo, setPinNo] = useState("");
  const [BranchNo, setBranchNo] = useState("");
  const [BranchHq, setBranchHq] = useState("");
  const [StartDate, setStartDate] = useState("");
  const [EndDate, setEndDate] = useState("");
  const [Current, setCurrent] = useState("");
  const [RunDate, setRunDate] = useState("");
  const [DateCreated, setDateCreated] = useState("");
  const [UserID, setUserID] = useState("");
  const [LocationID, setLocationID] = useState("");

  const history = useHistory();

  const argu = props.match.params.CmpnyCode;

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/getcomcode/" + argu).then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
      const variables = response.data;
      return variables;
    });
  }, [argu]);

  const editData = () => {
    axios.put("http://localhost:8000/upcompanymst/" + argu, {
      CmpnyCode: CmpnyCode,
      CmpnyName: CmpnyName,
      Address1: Address1,
      Address2: Address2,
      PoBox: PoBox,
      City: City,
      Province: Province,
      Country: Country,
      Phone: Phone,
      Fax: Fax,
      Email: Email,
      RegistrationNo: RegistrationNo,
      VatNo: VatNo,
      PinNo: PinNo,
      BranchNo: BranchNo,
      BranchHq: BranchHq,
      StartDate: StartDate,
      EndDate: EndDate,
      Current: Current,
      RunDate: RunDate,
      DateCreated: DateCreated,
      UserID: UserID,
      LocationID: LocationID,
    });
    history.push("/companymst");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <form>
            <h3> Edit Company Master</h3>
            {data.map((val) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div className="form-class8">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Company Code</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="CompanyCode"
                        defaultValue={val.CmpnyCode}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setCmpnyCode(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="CmpnyCode"
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Company Name</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="CompanyName"
                        defaultValue={val.CmpnyName}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setCmpnyName(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="CmpnyName"
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Address1</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Address1"
                        defaultValue={val.Address1}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setAddress1(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="Address1"
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Address2</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Address2"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setAddress2(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="Address2"
                        defaultValue={val.Address2}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>PO Box</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="PO Box"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setPoBox(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="PoBox"
                        defaultValue={val.PoBox}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>City</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="City"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setCity(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="City"
                        defaultValue={val.City}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Province</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Province"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setProvince(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="Province"
                        defaultValue={val.Province}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Country</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Country"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setCountry(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="Country"
                        defaultValue={val.Country}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-class8">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Phone</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Phone"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setPhone(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="Phone"
                        defaultValue={val.Phone}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Fax</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Fax"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setFax(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="Fax"
                        defaultValue={val.Fax}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Email</label>
                      <input
                        type="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setEmail(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="Email"
                        defaultValue={val.Email}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Registration No</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="RegistrationNo"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setRegistrationNo(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="RegistrationNo"
                        defaultValue={val.RegistrationNo}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>VAT No</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="VAT No"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setVatNo(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="VatNo"
                        defaultValue={val.VatNo}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Pin No</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Pin No"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setPinNo(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="PinNo"
                        defaultValue={val.PinNo}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Branch No</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Branch No"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setBranchNo(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="BranchNo"
                        defaultValue={val.BranchNo}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Branch Hq</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Branch Hq"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setBranchHq(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="BranchHq"
                        defaultValue={val.BranchHq}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-class8">
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Start Date</label>
                      <input
                        type="date"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Start Date"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setStartDate(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="StartDate"
                        defaultValue={val.StartDate}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>End Date</label>
                      <input
                        type="date"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="End Date"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setEndDate(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="EndDate"
                        defaultValue={val.EndDate}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Current</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Current"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setCurrent(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="Current"
                        defaultValue={val.Current.data[0]}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Run Date</label>
                      <input
                        type="date"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Run Date"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setRunDate(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="RunDate"
                        defaultValue={val.RunDate}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Date Created</label>
                      <input
                        type="date"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Date Created"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setDateCreated(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="DateCreated"
                        defaultValue={val.DateCreated}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>User ID</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="User ID"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setUserID(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="UserID"
                        defaultValue={val.UserID}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label>Location ID</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Location ID"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                          setLocationID(e.target.value);
                        }}
                        name="LocationID"
                        defaultValue={val.LocationID}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                    onClick={() => editData()}
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(CompanyMaster_Edit);
```

**The companylist from where I am getting the props.match.params.CmpnyCode:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Container, Row, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const AllCompanies = () => {
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/companymst").then((response) => {
      setCompanies(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const deleteRecord = (CmpnyCode) => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/deletecompanymst/${CmpnyCode}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <Container className="container">
            <Row className="row">
              <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>CompanyCode</th>
                    <th>CompanyName</th>
                    <th>Address1</th>
                    <th>Address2</th>
                    <th>PoBox</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Province</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Fax</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>RegistrationNo</th>
                    <th>VatNo</th>
                    <th>PinNo</th>
                    <th>BranchNo</th>
                    <th>BranchHq</th>
                    <th>StartDate</th>
                    <th>EndDate</th>
                    <th>Current</th>
                    <th>RunDate</th>
                    <th>DateCreated</th>
                    <th>UserID</th>
                    <th>LocationID</th>
                    <th colSpan="2">Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {companies.map((val) => {
                    return (
                      <tr>
                        <td>{val.CmpnyCode}</td>
                        <td>{val.CmpnyName}</td>
                        <td>{val.Address1}</td>
                        <td>{val.Address2}</td>
                        <td>{val.PoBox}</td>
                        <td>{val.City}</td>
                        <td>{val.Province}</td>
                        <td>{val.Country}</td>
                        <td>{val.Phone}</td>
                        <td>{val.Fax}</td>
                        <td>{val.Email}</td>
                        <td>{val.RegistrationNo}</td>
                        <td>{val.VatNo}</td>
                        <td>{val.PinNo}</td>
                        <td>{val.BranchNo}</td>
                        <td>{val.BranchHq}</td>
                        <td>{val.StartDate}</td>
                        <td>{val.EndDate}</td>
                        <td>{val.Current.data[0]}</td>
                        <td>{val.RunDate}</td>
                        <td>{val.DateCreated}</td>
                        <td>{val.UserID}</td>
                        <td>{val.LocationID}</td>
                        <td>
                          <Link to={`/upcompanymaster/${val.CmpnyCode}`}>
                            <Button variant="info">Edit</Button>
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Button
                            variant="danger"
                            onClick={() => {
                              deleteRecord(val.CmpnyCode);
                            }}
                          >
                            Delete
                          </Button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllCompanies;
```

My guess here is that the null variables is because I have passed ("") to the useState of every variable hence they being overwritten as null.
Can someone please help me on how I can prevent that?
I am new to this so even if this sounds silly please help me out as I have been stuck here for a week now.

And please note that I want to be able to edit any field of my choice not just one specific field.

Comment: Can you share a code sandbox so I can look more into it ? Also, when you have complicated or a lot of states it's kinda better to use a Reducer (Reducer hook)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? 
I don't know how to use Reducer Hook

Comment: In your `useEffect` set the state of each of your inputs instead of adding everything to `data` and using `defaultValue`. You do want to control the values so setting the state after your fetch will make sure the data you sent to your backend is the data that was fetched

Comment: @Dominik will you please help me edit my code in that way because I tried doind that but I got an undefined error

Comment: Added an answer :)

Comment: (1) is there any particular reason for sending all fields back to the database instead of just the updated ones? (2) if you change just one field, only the relevant state variable will be updated while all the others will keep their initial values of `""` (empty string); when you send the data back for the update all those empty strings will be written in the DB.

Comment: @GregMit Please refer to this https://github.com/Chirag-Maurya/CRM-App.git

Comment: @ChiragMaurya let me know if you got issues with my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you were doing before is you where assigning data coming from a fetch to all your inputs via `defaultValue` and then attaching state only to the `onChange`. This means that when you submit your data and that state, it will send all default values (which are empty strings as you pointed out in your question) except for this that have been changed.

Instead of using a different state object `data` for all your fetched data use the actual states for each input and then change `defaultValue` to `value` so the input becomes a controled input.

So now when you save the input *(which should REALLY be an `onSubmit` on the form and not an `onClick` on the button btw)* the data sent to your back end is what is actually reflected in your form.

You should also stick your fetch into a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array to make sure it runs only once on mount.

*(I simplified the code a bit to make it easier to understand what to do)*

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function CompanyMaster_Edit(props) {
    const [CmpnyCode, setCmpnyCode] = useState("");
    const [CmpnyName, setCmpnyName] = useState("");
    // etc...

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/getcomcode/" + argu).then((response) => {
            setCmpnyCode(response.data[0].CmpnyCode);
            setCmpnyName(response.data[0].CmpnyName);
            // etc...

        });
    }, [argu]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const editData = () => {
            axios.put("http://localhost:8000/upcompanymst/" + argu, {
                CmpnyCode,
                CmpnyName,
                /// etc...
            });
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="auth-wrapper">
                <div className="auth-inner">
                    <form>
                        <h3> Edit Company Master</h3>
                        {data.map((val) => {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    <div className="form-class8">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label>Company Code</label>
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                className="form-control"
                                                placeholder="CompanyCode"
                                                value={CmpnyCode}
                                                onChange={(e) => {
                                                    setCmpnyCode(e.target.value);
                                                }}
                                                name="CmpnyCode"
                                            />
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label>Company Name</label>
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                className="form-control"
                                                placeholder="CompanyName"
                                                value={CmpnyName}
                                                onChange={(e) => {
                                                    setCmpnyName(e.target.value);
                                                }}
                                                name="CmpnyName"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    {/* etc ... */}

                                    </div>

                                    <button
                                        className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                                        onClick={() => editData()}
                                    >
                                        Edit
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default withRouter(CompanyMaster_Edit);
```

Comment: now I don't have my data from the database being shown in the form 
All I get is a blank form

Comment: I think that might be because your fetch was not in a `useEffect`. Try that

Comment: I have checked everything. The issue here is that response.data.CmpnyCode etc are all undefined when I console.log them

Comment: I just figured it out. Since response,data was an Array of objects I did response.data[0].CmpnyCode etc and it worked. And now even my data edits correctly.
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Great... glad it worked. I don't know the shape of you data but I'll maker an edit for you

Comment: Cool. No worries